# Problems with ROSARIA

Tags: ros, pioneer, rosaria, aria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I got a probem with running Pioneer. Please help me.
I installed a package ROSARIA to my robot P3-DX and it works well.
But what i want to do is to move the robot by keyboard. By the way, I found that there are many source code in the Aria package such as ArActionKeydrive.cpp ArActionInput.cpp etc.
I want to know how to use these useful codes at the same time.

thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47132/problems-with-rosaria/) by [Blake](https://answers.ros.org/users/3502/blake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-10-31**:
I don't have any experience with ROSARIA, but so far I have had no problem with p2os with both the Pioneer P3-DX and P3-AT. If you are not determined to use Aria specifically, I could try to help you get started.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-10-31**:
I also use the Pioneer-3DX robots. I have set up 3 of them for ros. I definitely recommend you approach this with P2OS instead of ROSARIA. You can even avoid setting up a separate laptop for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would use a ROS "client" node that sends messages to RosAria's `/RosAria/cmd_vel` topic to control robot velocity.  See "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber" at http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials to get started writing  your own client.

Some examples you can start from is available at https://github.com/pengtang/rosaria_client, including a simple teleoperation using keyboard control.

Another one that uses Python is http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard, just map its `cmd_vel` output topic to `/RosAria/cmd_vel` or vice-versa.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0